# Fop - streaming PDF

Tags: java, xslt, fonts, apache-fop

I want to make pdf stream. Without trying to add special characters it use to works, but with this part it doesn't streaming my pdf from third line

```
DefaultConfigurationBuilder cfgBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
File file1 = new File("fonts.xsl");   
Configuration cfg = cfgBuilder.buildFromFile(file1);
fopFactory.setUserConfig(cfg);
```

Here is link to this  [fonts.xsl](http://pastebin.com/2pWkCNZ5)
And class with that code [FOPdpf](http://pastebin.com/kkuaVCht)